# How can you display a list of images as a navigation bar's title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistackview

From stackoverflowing, I understand that to set the title of a navigation bar to an image, we use the following code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

However, I want to display a list of images CENTERED on the navigation bar. It's for a chat application where I display the images of all the participants! So I do need some space between the UIImages.

I was thinking horizontal stackviews but I'm not sure how to properly implement them programmatically. Or even if it's possible to do so in the navigation bar.

Does anyone know how to do this effectively?

Thanks in advance!

PS: As an aside, would anyone happen to know how to increase the height of the navigation bar? I've tried the following code in viewDidAppear:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAlways;
self.navigationController.navigationBar sizeToFit];
```

But the result is NOT static. I have a tableview underneath to display the chat messages and if I scroll to a certain point, the big navigation bar CONDENSES. Moreover, the font is magnified. Is there a way to statically set the height of a navigation bar in iOS 11+ without affecting any other properties of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can display anything you like in the center of the navigation bar as its `titleView`. So create your containing view with the horizontally arranged image views as its subviews, set up all the needed constraints, and use your containing view as the title view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do using your stackView

let you will add 3 imageViews, `imageView1`, `imageView2`, `imageView3`

```
stackView.addArrangedSubViews([imageView1, imageView2, imageView3])

self.navigationItem.titleView = stackView
```